# Role conflict when updating EKS addon

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I am trying to update the eks add-on named "vpc-cni". This plugin, does the following:

"The CNI plugin allows Kubernetes Pods to have the same IP address as they do on the VPC network. More specifically, all containers inside the Pod share a network namespace, and they can communicate with each-other using local ports."

I am however getting the following "Conflict" when updating:

```
Conflicts: ClusterRole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io aws-node - .rules DaemonSet.apps aws-node - .spec.template.spec.containers[name="aws-node"].image DaemonSet.apps aws-node - .spec.template.spec.initContainers[name="aws-vpc-cni-init"].image
```

I don't really know where to begin in remediating this, or even what this error conflict is saying is conflicting.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: could you please share the code/process used to update the addon and exactly what you are updating?

Answer (score 10):

Work around: when deploying this addon in the AWS console, click on the "advanced options" in the first panel after specifying the version and the IAM role. At the very bottom is a button that can be selected to override conflicts and this allows the installation to succeed.

Comment: I did get this resolved somehow. Although I'm not sure I understood how. Guessing your answer will help someone else though!

Comment: Is there any danger of "overriding" a conflicting configuration?